# How to make a new dataframe containing each word and it's count using another columns

Tags: python, pandas

Let me explain. My `df`look like this:

```
id `  text                             c1      
1     Hello world how are you people    1 
2     Hello people I am fine  people    1
3     Good Morning people               -1
4     Good Evening                      -1
```

`c1` contains only two values 1 or -1

Now I want a dataframe (output) like this:

```
Word      Totalcount     Points      PercentageOfPointAndTotalCount

hello        2             2              100
world        1             1              100
how          1             1              100
are          1             1              100
you          1             1              100
people       3             1              33.33
I            1             1              100
am           1             1              100
fine         1             1              100
Good         2             -2            -100
Morning      1             -1            -100
Evening      1             -1            -100
```

Here, `Totalcount` is the total times each word appears in `text` column.

`points` is the sum of `c1` of each word. Example: `people` word is in two rows where `c1` is 1, and one row where `c1` is `-1`. So it's point is just 1 (2-1 = 1).

PercentageOfPointAndTotalCount = Points/TotalCount*100

`print(df)`

```
      id comment_text  target
0  59848  Hello world    -1.0
1  59849  Hello world    -1.0
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using [unnesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939) after `str.split,` then we just need `groupby` + `agg`

```
unnesting(df,['text']).groupby('text').c1.agg(['count','sum'])
Out[873]: 
         count  sum
text               
Evening      1   -1
Good         2   -2
Hello        2    2
I            1    1
Morning      1   -1
am           1    1
are          1    1
fine         1    1
how          1    1
people       4    2
world        1    1
you          1    1
```

---

```
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx = df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1 = pd.concat([
        pd.DataFrame({x: np.concatenate(df[x].values)}) for x in explode], axis=1)
    df1.index = idx

    return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1), how='left')
```

Comment: I am getting this error `ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated` on `pd.DataFrame` line

Comment: @johndoe you have empty line in text ? , just remove it :-) before unnesting , like `df=df[df.text!='']`

Comment: @johndoe your sample data is work fine, and you may need to find the different between the data you show to us with your real data

Comment: Thanks, let me find the difference. My real data contain millions of rows

Comment: I just called 2 rows,and still got the same error. I did print(df) and see the updated question to see the result

Answer (score 1):

Here's a self-contained version:

```
new_df = (df.set_index('c1').text.str.split().apply(pd.Series)
      .stack().reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1))

new_df.groupby(0).c1.agg(['sum','count'])
```

Output:

```
+---------+-----+-------+
|         | sum | count |
+---------+-----+-------+
|    0    |     |       |
+---------+-----+-------+
| Evening |  -1 |     1 |
| Good    |  -2 |     2 |
| Hello   |   2 |     2 |
| I       |   1 |     1 |
| Morning |  -1 |     1 |
| am      |   1 |     1 |
| are     |   1 |     1 |
| fine    |   1 |     1 |
| how     |   1 |     1 |
| people  |   2 |     4 |
| world   |   1 |     1 |
| you     |   1 |     1 |
+---------+-----+-------+
```